# Count all the records of a table using Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, mysql, performance, doctrine

I want to count all the records of a table using Doctrine ORM and I want it done in the fastest way possible.

I don't need the individual records of the table. I just need the total number of records in the table.

Is there a particular method that will give me the most ramming speed in terms of performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *fastest* is likely to bypass Doctrine and use raw SQL, but you can do:

```
Doctrine::getTable('tablename')->count();
```

Also see:

- [Doctrine Manual on Data Retrieval and Manipulation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html)

Comment: In a project that has the privilege of using Doctrine, I'd recommend to avoid raw SQL where ever it's possible. The "countable" Interface of Doctrine_Table is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

This example should work

```
public function executeTotal(sfWebRequest $r){
$total = Doctrine::getTable('Applicants')->findAll()->count();   
}
```